# Get all combinations of a slice until a certain length

Tags: go

I am using the go `combinations` package to find all the combinations of a list of `ints`. The package out of the box is for strings but I've edited to do `[]int` instead.

```golang
func All(set []int) (subsets [][]int) {
    length := uint(len(set))

    // Go through all possible combinations of objects
    // from 1 (only first object in subset) to 2^length (all objects in subset)
    for subsetBits := 1; subsetBits < (1 << length); subsetBits++ {
        var subset []int

        for object := uint(0); object < length; object++ {
            // checks if object is contained in subset
            // by checking if bit 'object' is set in subsetBits
            if (subsetBits>>object)&1 == 1 {
                // add object to subset
                subset = append(subset, set[object])
            }
        }
        // add subset to subsets
        subsets = append(subsets, subset)
    }
    return subsets
}
```

This works for me, however, only when given a small slice. once the slice gets large the combinations become exponential and tolling to calculate.

Luckily I know when I need to stop. Before running the combinations I have determined the max length of the combinations.

```golang
s := []int{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
limit := 2
```

The above would generate an exorbent amount of combinations, majority I will not need, as I can define the limit to the length of combinations I'd need as a maximum.

```golang
// Ideal output

[[2] [2] [2] [2] ......  [2 3] [2 4]] // Stop once we hit length of 3 as limit was set to 2
```

I can't really figure out how to implement a limit `break` or return once the combinations reach a certain length.

Example:

```golang
func All(set []int, limit int) (subsets [][]int) {
    // ... previous code here

    if len(combinations) > limit {
        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this package has what you are looking for: https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat/combin It is part of the [gonum](https://github.com/gonum) set of packages: https://www.gonum.org/

Comment: How large can `set` be? If using the same implementation, `All()` function can only support 63 elements (or 31 if using a 32-bit system).

Comment: @NickyLogan the hard limit is 150,000 elements, I am running into the issue that once a slice/array/list reaches a certain length it just doesn't work. Probably due to what you said.

Comment: That's a lot of elements, how high is the limit? Setting limit = 2 for 150k by itself is already very large (11,175,000,000 + 150,000 combinations!).